# UITapGestureRecognizer for UIImageView on UIScrollView never called iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am adding a UIImageView as a subview to a UIScrollView then i set the image.

Im trying to to use UITapGestureRecognizer.

The selector of the UITapGestureRecognizer is never called in iOS 5 (in iOS 6 it DOES!).
Tried many variations. this is my code:

```
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(index*(IMAGE_WIDTH+10), 10.0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
    [imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:meal.RecommendedImageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
    imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    [imgView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imgView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    [scrollView addSubview:imgView];

    if (IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_5)    
    {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [tapGestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
    }
```

this is my selector which is only called in iOS5:

```
 - (void) imageTapped: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    //Code to handle the gesture
    UIImageView *tappedImageView = (UIImageView*)recognizer.view;
    GGFullscreenImageViewController *vc = [[GGFullscreenImageViewController alloc] init];
    vc.liftedImageView = tappedImageView;
    vc.liftedImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    if (IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_5) {
        [self.parentViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }


}
```

In addition to that, i tried to setCancelsTouchesInView to YES in my UIScrollView but it doesn't work either.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: still not being called

Comment: have you added the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
to your header-file?

Comment: is there any others gestures are present?

Comment: nope, this is the only one i am adding

Comment: if (IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_5) means you want to add gestures for iphone5?

Comment: You should check for gesture support with `if (UITapGestureRecognizer.class)`. This is backwards compatible with basically every iOS version. You just compile with the latest SDK.

Comment: @Sunny - no, it means only >= iOS 5

Comment: Once check your scroll view content size.whether your image view is with the scroll view content on=r not

Answer (score 0):

```
   try to add Gesture in Scrollview then check iskind of class image view
      UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
    [scrollview addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [tapGestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];

       - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
         // test if our control subview is on-screen
           if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
           // we touched a button, slider, or other UIControl
             return YES;
           }return NO;
        }
```

Comment: when i am using your code the touch get recognized also when i scroll the images, i want to call it only user tapped

Comment: so..try above code but..add gesture in your imageview     [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer]; nd also must be set delegate in .h

Comment: still nothing...
the scorllview is a subview of a UITableViewCell`s content view, maybe it has something with that?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the 3 methods of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate & return default values:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```

Comment: when i am using your code the touch get recognized also when i scroll the images, i want to call it only user tapped

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it very EASILY! 
the problem was setting the delegate of the UITapGestureRecognizer to self.
when i removed the delegate = self, it started working :)
Thanks for your assistance